# groovy invoke dynamic Impact on divide operation

Tags: java, groovy

### my evniment:

groovy 3.0.8
jvm 1.8
system window10

### my problem

Same groovy source code,
if I close invoke dynamic the run result is inconsistent with open invoke dynamic.

my source code:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 3 / 2
        println a
    }
```

compile with close invoke dynamic. will print result: 1.0

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        double a = 0.0D;
        if (BytecodeInterface8.isOrigInt() && BytecodeInterface8.isOrigD() && !__$stMC && !BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass()) {
            int var5 = 3 / 2;
            a = (double)var5;
        } else {
            Object var4 = var1[0].call(3, 2);
            a = DefaultTypeTransformation.doubleUnbox(var4);
        }

        var1[1].callStatic(AA.class, a);
    }
```

compile with open invoke dynamic,will print result 1.5

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        double a = DefaultTypeTransformation.doubleUnbox(true.invoke<invokedynamic>(3, 2));
        AA.class.invoke<invokedynamic>(AA.class, a);
    }
```

### my expect result

The output should be the same whether it is closed or open

Comment: What about `double a = 3 / 2.0` so you're not doing integer division?

Comment: when I want verify difference between groovy divide  and  java divide. 
I find this strange phenomenon with open or close  invoke dynamic

Comment: if I switch `def a = 3 / 2`, it will work well and meet expectations